# Reading 2d array from a file into python list

Tags: python

I am trying to read a 2d array of comma separated values from a file into a list. I have the following problem, how do I get rid of trailing newlines? This is what I mean. This is one row I have read.

```
['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1\n']
```

Presently, I have the following in code:

```
ins = open( "parseTable.txt", "r" )
parseTable = []
for line in ins:
    row = line.split(',')
    parseTable.append(row)
```

Thanks everybody for the tips. I did the following to make do.
thanks for all the tips. I did the following to make do.

```
ins = open( "parseTable.txt", "r" )
parseTable = []
for line in ins:
    row = line.split(',')
    parseTable.append(map(int,line.split(',')))
```

Comment: maybe `ast.literal_eval` can help

Comment: @frodo Glad you found the code and tips provided helpful. You may want to upvote the answers you found useful, and select one of them as your answer via the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

The only change necessary to your existing code is the use of the `rstrip()` function on your line before you `split()` it. e.g.,

```
ins = open( "parseTable.txt", "r" )  # the "r" is not really needed - default 
parseTable = []

for line in ins:
   row = line.rstrip().split(',')  # <- note use of rstrip()
   parseTable.append(row)
```

This will eliminate the trailing newline as requested.

---

A simple example, step by step:

```
In [2]: s = 'this is a test\n'

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 'this is a test\n'

In [4]: s.rstrip()
Out[4]: 'this is a test'
```

So in order for the changes to stick you need to make assignments

```
In [5]: s = s.rstrip()

In [6]: s = s.split()

In [7]: s
Out[7]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Alternatively in one step:

```
 In [11]: s = s.rstrip().split()

 In [12]: s
 Out[12]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Answer (score 1):

With `with` statement, list comprehension, and `csv` module

```
import csv
with open("parseTable.txt") as f:
    parseTable = [x.rstrip() for x in row for row in csv.reader(f)]
```

Edit:

1. `with` statement will close you file automatically when exception raises while opening/processing file. It may not be necessary in your case but you should remember of this possibility. Using context managers is a good practice [ [More](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) ]
2. List comprehension usually makes your script faster but sometimes harder for readability. Anyway you have to understand and use it.
3. I don't mean anything in favour `csv` module or against opening files with built-in functions and splitting rows with `split(',')`. It's your choice, I just suggest the alternative.

Comment: This worked for me   ins = open( "parseTable.txt", "r" )
parseTable = []
for line in ins:
    row = line.split(',')
    parseTable.append(map(int,line.split(',')))

Answer (score 0):

```
t = []
for line in open("txt", "r").readlines():
    t.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
```